# Using Satellite Server to provision CentOS

Tags: centos, provisioning, satellite

Using RedHat Satellite Server 6.7, is there a way to provision bare-metal CentOS systems?

Satellite Server generally supports CentOS for updates.

Satellite Server also supports a very simple method to provision new RedHat Enterprise Linux systems using PXE (or a boot ISO image) and auto-generated Kickstart files. I use it frequently.

But I have not been able to find a way for Satellite Server to provision CentOS the same way.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: I can't imagine why it wouldn't work. What problem are you having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Basically, none of the infrastructure RHEL uses seems to be there for CentOS. RHEL pulls the Kickstart files (a fairly complicated nested set of Kickstart files) from a special Kickstart repository. I'm also not sure if the iPXE booting that kicks off the installer would work with CentOS.

Comment: As you noted, it's very easy easy to patch CentOS servers (I do that quite often as well). I haven't tried to provision CentOS from Satellite, but I wonder if you could do it with Foreman (the upstream project to Satellite).

Comment: @MichaelHampton You were right, it worked right out of the box. I hadn't expected that. Please feel free to make this an answer so I can upvote it.